# Comparing two tables with results showing paired matches

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

so I have two tables that I need to compare the data and produce a result set where the data are identical for specific columns and the data needs to be displayed with alternating rows.  For example in the following diagram col2 and col3 are compared, and where they are identical they are paired up in the result table.

```
       table1                   table2                    result

col1    col2    col3      col1    col2  col3        col1    col2   col3

 1      111     222        1      222   333          1      111    222  
 2      222     333        2      333   444          3      111    222
 3      333     444        3      111   222          2      222    333
                           4      222   333          1      222    333
                                                     4      222    333
                                                     3      333    444
                                                     2      333    444
```

Is this possible with a single sql statement? Each table can have upwards of 20,000+ records so I rather not go through line by line.  Thanks!

Comment: col2 and col3 values are always identical? If so why compare both? If not why you added misleading example? What type of columns?

Comment: good point, no they would not be identical.  I tried to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: ok your edit confused me. Do you mean identical as in `111` are all the same digits or `col2 = 111 and col3 = 111` so they are a match?

Comment: EXISTS might be useful here if I have read your question correctly

Comment: I mean col1 = col1 and col2 = col2.  I think UNION will be the best way to go as suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this statement if the order of col1 is not important.

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table1
union
select col1, col2, col3
from table2
order by col2, col3
```